# DB Schema: Why not create new table for each 'entity'?

Tags: sql, database

Sorry about the vague title. 
An example: I'm guessing SO has one large table that lists all answers, in a schema like:
[ Ques No, Ans No, Text , Points ]
[ 22,      0     , "Win", 3      ],
[ 22,      1     , "Tin", 4      ],
[ 23,      0     , "Pin", 2      ]

My question is would it be better if there were two tables: Table_Ques22 and Table_Ques23? Can someone please list the pros and cons?

What comes to my mind: 
Cons of multiple tables: Overhead of meta storage. 
Pros of multiple tables: Quickly answer queries like, find all answers to Ques 22. (I know there are indices, but they take time to build and space to maintain).

Comment: You tend to build a database schema to support more than a single query. Yes, it's very quick to find all answers to a question. Try writing the query to find all answers by a particular user.

Comment: Don't be afraid of indexes, their costs are usually overstated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Databases are designed to handle large tables.  Having multiple tables with the same structure introduces a lot of problems.  These come to mind:

- Queries that span multiple rows ("questions" in your example) become much more complicated and performance suffers.
- Maintaining similar entities is cumbersome.  Adding an index or partitioning a single table is one thing.  Doing it to hundreds of tables is much harder.
- Maintaining triggers is cumbersome.
- When a new row appears (new question), you have to incur the overhead of creating a table rather than just adding to an existing table.
- Altering a table, say to add a new column or rename an existing one, is very cumbersome.

Although putting all questions in one table does use a small additional amount of storage, you have to balance that against the overhead of having very small tables.  A table with data has to occupy at least one data page, regardless of whether the data is 10 bytes or 10 Gbytes.  If a data page is 16 kbytes, that is a lot of wasted space to support multiple tables for a singe entity.

As for database limits.  I'm not even sure a database could support a separate table for each question on Stack Overflow.

There is one case where having parallel table structures is useful.  That is when security requirements require that the data be separated, perhaps for client confidentiality reasons.  However, this is often an argument for separate *databases*, not just separate *tables*.

Comment: Great answer, perhaps you can also mention partitioning

Answer (score 0):

What about: SQL Servers are not made for people ignoring the basics of the relational theoream.

You ahve a ton of problems with cross question queries in your part, which will totally kill all the gains. Typical beginner mistake - I suggest a good book about SQL basics.

Comment: This is not really an answer more like a comment; anyway, you were mentioning a good SQL book, perhaps you will share a link with user247077

Comment: Sure, Google.com. MSDN.Microsoft.com - the documentation is quite good. SQL for DUmmies, like always, the dummies books are quite good.